# Find j,k such that $2^j + 3 = 7^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all $j,k$ such that $2^j + 3 = 7^k$.

I think that the only solution is $j=2$. Because of the exponential growth of $2$ and $7$. But I am not that sure.

Comment: Do $j$ and $k$ have to be positive integers?

Comment: The exponential growth is not exactly the point here... $i$ and $j$ dont need to be close. You have to think about residues... What can you learn about $j$ since $2^j\equiv -3 \operatorname{mod} 7$... Then use that to get information about $k$, etc...

Comment: Please do not make changes to the question that do not improve anything and yet make existing answers and comments meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, by inspection, $j=2, k=1$.

We also have that $7^k \equiv \{7,1\}\bmod 8$, so no higher values of $j,k$ will work.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Look at it mod $8$......

Comment: fermat's little theorem here or am i wrong?

Comment: @NikosM. Simply $7^k \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$, while $2^j \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ is $ j \ge 3$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite
$$2^a+3=7^b=(8-1)^b=\sum^{b}_{k=0}{b\choose k}8^{b-k}(-1)^k$$

Denote the $r^{th}$ term of the binomial expansion be $T_r$. We have
$$T_{b-k}={b\choose b-k}8^k(-1)^{b-k}={b\choose k}8^k(-1)^{b-k}$$
$$\therefore T_k+T_{b-k}={b\choose k}\left[8^k(-1)^{b-k}+8^{b-k}(-1)^k\right]$$

If $b=2p,p\in\Bbb{N}$, that is, there are even number of terms,
$$T_k+T_{b-k}=2{2p\choose k}8^k(-1)^{k}\neq7^{2p}$$

While for $b=2p+1$, $$T_k+T_{b-k}=(-1)^{k-1}{2p+1\choose k}\left[8^k-8^{2p+1-k}\right]$$

which is even.

This implies the middle term $T_{p+1}={2p+1\choose p+1}(-1)^{p+1}8^p$ has to be odd.

$\therefore p=0,b=1,a=2$

Comment: Please use LaTeX. It is easy to find a comprehensive guide on Meta.

Comment: Sorry for my poor-quality old post. I'll fix it soon.